# Why are new icons inserted between locked icons (instead after locked items) in the Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I have a launcher like this with a couple of locked items:

[image]

I use this feature a lot to use Super+[0-9] to quickly access recurring apps. Now if I open a new application the icon is inserted between the first and the second locked icon instead after all locked items. Say I open Thunderbird over Unity search:

[image]

Now it's inserted at position 2 which obviously breaks my Super+Num keys for any following locked item. The only thing to work around this would be to lock this icon as well, but that's not what I want to do. Standard behaviour anywhere else I know (Windows, MacOS) is that unknown apps are appended after all locked items.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can drag the icon wherever you want

Comment: I am aware of that. But I don't want to drag the icon everytime I open an app that was not locked on the launcher. BTW: Dragging the icon automatically locks the icon on the launcher - that's the next thing I wouldn't want.

Comment: Oh and one more thing: This actually is standard behaviour in unity as well. It changed recently. So something seems to be messed up.

Comment: Oh too bad. I just wanted to give you a medal and tons of credits because you were completely right ;)

Comment: Ah, I just deleted too early :)

Comment: Thank you very much, Jacob! This way I can even get rid of the  launcher icons when I mounted an external device.